# Is $\pi^1:C_c(G)\rightarrow \operatorname{End}(H)$ a homomorphism of the convolution algebra when $G$ is not unimodular?

Tags: measure-theory, representation-theory, convolution, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff locally compact group and $H$ a Banach space. Let $\pi:G\rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(H)$ be a representation and define

$$\pi^1(\phi)v = \int_G\phi(x)\pi(x)vdx$$

for $v\in H$ and $\phi$ a compactly supported function on $G$. Then, Lang shows in his book $\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb R)$, p.5, that $\pi^1$ is a homomorphism of the convolution product with the following lines.

$$\begin{aligned} \pi^1(\phi \ast \psi) &= \int_G(\phi\ast\psi) (x)\pi(x)dx \\
&= \int_G\int_G\phi(xy^{-1})\psi(y)\pi(x)dydx \\
&= \int_G\int_G\phi(x)\psi(y)\pi(x)\pi(y)dxdy \\
&= \pi^1(\phi)\pi^1(\psi)\end{aligned}$$

Where from the second to third line he swapped the order of integration and $x\mapsto xy$. But this only works because $G$ is unimodular, right? Otherwise, shouldn't we get a factor of $\Delta(y)$?

Comment: So $\int_G\ldots dx$ means integrating with respect to the Haar measure on $G$. Maybe you can change your notation so that the unimodular / left/right invariant problem is more explicit ?

Comment: If $f(x) = 1_{x \in S}$ then $\int_G f(x) dx  = \mu(S)$, thus $f(x y^{-1}) = 1_{x y^{-1} \in S} = 1_{x \in Sy}$ and $\int_G f(xy^{-1}) dx = \mu(Sy) \ne \mu(S)$
by definition of the left invariance of the Haar measure $\mu$. But you can consider instead another integral $\int_G 1_{x \in S} dx  = \nu(S)$ where $\nu(S)$ is right invariant, and then everything works well. Otherwise you can keep the left invariant Haar measure, and define the convolution as $\phi \ast \psi(y) = \int_G \phi(y^{-1}x) \psi(y)dy$ and again everything works well.

Comment: That's what I thought. Depending on the invariance that you have, one definition of convolution or the other may be more suitable.

Comment: (I'm not sure of what I wrote) how is defined $\int_G f(x) dx$ ?  and did you check if $\ast$ is associative (I'd say it should because $\pi^1$ is) ?

Comment: $dx$ is meant as the unimodular Haar measure on $G$ in that page of the book. I wanted to know what would happen if we did not assume that $G$ was unimodular and had to make a choice for the right- or left-invariant measure.

Comment: I checked associativity : if $a\ast b(x)=\int_G a(y^{-1}x)b(y)dy$ and $\int_G f(gy)dy=\int_G f(y)dy$ then $$(a \ast b) \ast c(z)=\int_G a\ast b(x^{-1}z) c(x) dx =\int_G (\int_G a(y^{-1}x^{-1}z) b(y) dy) c(x) dx$$ with $f(y) = a(y^{-1}x^{-1}z) b(y)$, $f(x^{-1}y) = a(y^{-1}z) b(x^{-1}y)$ so $$(a \ast b) \ast c(z) = \int_G (\int_G a(y^{-1}z) b(x^{-1}y) dy) c(x) dx$$ while $a \ast (b \ast c)(z) = \int_G a(y^{-1}z) b \ast c(y) dy= \int_G a(y^{-1}z) (\int_G b(x^{-1}y) c(x) dx) dy $ $=\int_G\int_G a(y^{-1}z)  b(x^{-1}y)c(x)dxdy=\int_G(\int_G a(y^{-1}z)  b(x^{-1}y)  dy) c(x) dx = (a \ast b)\ast c(z)$

Comment: but I don't think the definition you used at first : $\int_G f(gy)dy=\int_G f(y)dy$ and $a\ast b(x)=\int_G a(xy^{-1})b(y)dy$ was associative, so no need of $\pi$ and $\pi^1$ for seing your definition was not correct in the non-unimodular case